# Best practice for scheduling tasks

Tags: mysql, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, scheduling, scheduler

I am developing a site where users will be able to run scheduled their own tasks. There will be a lot of tasks from each user.
Tasks can be of two types:
1. Tasks which will be run in the future at any time. (example: John want to post his message tomorrow in 5:25 pm).
2. Tasks which will be run in the future but in time which multiple 15 minutes. (example: John want to post his message tomorrow in 5:15 pm. He can't schedule this task on 5:25 because it isn't multiple 15 minutes. He can schedule it only on time like 5:15, 5:30, 5:45, 6:00 and so on).
What is the best practice to work with these tasks?
I have this idea:
Use a mysql database to store all tasks with index on time. Run a scheduler which will pull a task which must run soon and after this task pull next and so on.
Best Regards, Alexandr

Comment: I've had this issue, to help address it, I developed a service scheduledwebhook.com. It allows you to specify when an event should be triggered and the destination for the data. If this sounds like it might meet your needs, check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this framework https://quartz-scheduler.org/

What is Quartz?
Job Scheduling Library

Quartz is a richly featured, open source job scheduling library that can be integrated within virtually any Java application - from the smallest stand-alone application to the largest e-commerce system. Quartz can be used to create simple or complex schedules for executing tens, hundreds, or even tens-of-thousands of jobs; jobs whose tasks are defined as standard Java components that may execute virtually anything you may program them to do. The Quartz Scheduler includes many enterprise-class features, such as support for JTA transactions and clustering.